# homotopy equivalent maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am currently studying for an algebraic topology exam and want to show that
$
f,g:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}
$ for
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x,\sqrt{1-x^2}),g(x)=(x,-\sqrt{1-x^2})
\end{equation*}
are homotopy equivalent but not homotopy equivalent relative to $\{-1,1\}$.

What I have tried so far is the 'standard' homotopy \begin{equation*}
F(x,t)=(x,tf(x)+(1-t)g(x))\end{equation*}
but by doing so, I'll hit $(0,0)$ for $(x,t)=(0,\frac{1}{2})$ so that does not work.

I also assume that I should show the second result via contradiction but don't know how to start here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand, visually/conceptually, why the two functions are "obviously" homotopic but not homotopic relative to their end points?

Comment: The problem is $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ has a hole. Thus the standard homotopy doesn't work here because you can't simply "push down" the upper semicircle to the bottom semicircle leaving fixed the circles' endopoints.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes: to show homotopy, I can simply 'turn' the graphs to get the other map but I have to move the endpoints. This is also the reason why I cannot have homotopy relative to their endpoints. However, I would really like an explicit description of the homotopy in the first case.

Comment: You can just do the following for an explicit homotopy: Let $F(x,t)=\begin{cases}f(x-2t(x+1))&t\leq\frac12\\g(x-2(1-t)(x+1))&t\geq\frac12\end{cases}$ or something: Just contract $f$ to a point, then expand the point to $g$ (I hope my formula is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

$$H:[-1,1]\times[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$$
$$H(x,t)=f(tx)$$

and note that this is a homotopy from constant $f(0)$ map to $f(x)$. Analogously $$H'(x,t)=g(tx)$$

is a homotopy from constant $g(0)$ map to $g(x)$. In particular both are homotopic to some constant map, and since $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$ is path connected, then they are homotopic.

Note that this is a special case of more general fact: every two maps between contractible and path connected space are homotopic (in non-relative sense).

---

Now assume that there is a homotopy $H:[-1,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$ relative to $\{-1,1\}$, which means such that $H(-1,t)=(-1,0)$ and $H(1,t)=(1,0)$. Moreover $H(x,0)=g(x)$, $H(x,1)=f(x)$. So we know precisely how $H$ is defined on the boundary, we should utilize this fact. Consider

$$H':[-1,1]\times[0,1]\to S^1$$
$$H'(x,t)=\frac{H(x,t)}{\lVert H(x,t)\lVert}$$

First of all note that $H'(x,t)=H(x,t)$ on the boundary of $[-1,1]\times[0,1]$.

Now we will apply a non-relative homotopy to this homotopy map. Because why not? :)

The domain of $H'$ is contractible and thus $H'$ is homotopic to a constant map. By restricting $H'$ to the boundary, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$ we obtain a map $S^1\to S^1$ that is homotopic to a constant map as well. But $H'$ restricted to boundary is actually homotopic to the identity (this precisely where "being relative to $\{-1,1\}$" condition matters and requires some manual calculations). Contradiction because $S^1$ is not contractible. Hence no such $H$ can exist.